# Grails app running on two different domains

Tags: java, grails

I'm trying to make grails app run under two different domains - `test.com/myapp` and `test.org/myapp`. `host` in `Config.groovy` url is pointing to `https://test.com/myapp` What happens is when I go to `test.org/myapp` it goes properly to the home page and when I'm trying to login it redirects to the first domain. I guess it's something to be with spring security and path generating. What are my options in order to fix that?

Here is my `myapp.conf` but if you need additional data pls let me know in comments

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ "/var/www/html/certbot/.well-known/acme-challenge/"
  <Directory "/.well-known/acme-challenge/">
       Options -Indexes -MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/honeypot/
    RewriteEngine On
    php_flag engine off
    RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo

    JkMount /*      worker1
    JkUnMount /myapp/files/* worker1
    Alias "/myapp/files" "/var/www/myapp/files"
    <Directory "/myapp/files">
            allow from all
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/chain.pem

     SSLProxyEngine on
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPassMatch ^/myap(.+)$ !
     ProxyPass / https://myserver.com/
     ProxyPassReverse / https://myserver.com/
  </VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE**
`grails.serverURL = https://test.com/myapp`

Comment: can show your config.groovy file.

Comment: grails.serverURL  what is this parameter in config.groovy?

Comment: @DipakThoke `https://test.com/myapp`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should post your configuration for spring-security. Assuming it is that problem, there are different ways to tackle it. One is that you can set external configuration in Grails applications using grails.config.locations (see http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/single.html#configExternalized) and then you override the application settings for Spring Security within an external file on your server that the grails.config.locations is referencing.

This allows you to manage the application configuration separately, but deploy the same war. You could then manage the external files by some configuration management system, such as Puppet.